# Laravel download only if field is not empty

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5

I have a field called 'ical' which contains an url, but what I want to do is to run a function download a file using the url, however when field is empty ignore that row. At the moment what it does it downloads a file for each row and if there was a url it's filled in with data which is correct but when field was empty it downloaded a file but of course it is empty, and instead I just want to completely ignore that row if empty.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Entity;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Ixudra\Curl\Facades\Curl;

class DownloadIcal extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'ical:download';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Download all ICAL files from ical field in businesses database';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $entities = Entity::pluck('ical', 'id');
        foreach ( $entities as $entityID => $entityIcal ) {
            $response = Curl::to($entityIcal)
                ->download('public/ical/'.$entityID.'.ics');
                $this->info("ICal Retrieved");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this `foreach ( $entities as $entityID => $entityIcal ) {
 if( $entityIcal ){
     $response = Curl::to($entityIcal)
         ->download('public/ical/'.$entityID.'.ics');
         $this->info("ICal Retrieved");
 }
}` !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is use `if` inside the loop and check if value is empty or null.

```
$entities = Entity::pluck('ical', 'id');

foreach ( $entities as $entityID => $entityIcal ) 
{
    if ( !is_null($entityIcal) and !empty($entityIcal))
    {
        $response = Curl::to($entityIcal)
        ->download('public/ical/'.$entityID.'.ics');
        $this->info("ICal Retrieved");
    }
}
```